# Where does the factor of $1/V^N$ come from in the classical non-ideal partition function?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, partition-function

I'm reading about classical non-ideal gases from this [source](http://personal.rhul.ac.uk/UHAP/027/PH4211/PH4211_files/Chapter3.pdf). On page 5, they say that the non-ideal partition function is a product of the ideal partition function and the non-ideal partition function, which makes perfect sense.

They write the interaction part of the non-ideal partition function in equation (3.1.4) as

$$
\frac{1}{V^N} \int \mathrm{e}^{-\left(\sum_{i<j} U(q_i, p_i)\right)/kT}\, \mathrm{d}^{3N}q
$$

with no explanation as to where the factor $ 1/V^N$ comes from. I can't seem to figure it out in any sort of detail. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a convention choice, not every textbook uses this. It's been a while, but I think the choice to have that factor is due to the fact that the positions are uniformly distributed over the volume $V$, so we *choose* to perform the integral with this factor to represent this probability. So,

$$Q = \int \prod_i \left(\frac{d^3q_i}{V}\right) U(q_1, ... q_n)$$

It doesn't change the physics, since $V$ is a constant in these integrals anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a normalisation factor.

The total volume for one particle would be $V = \int \mathrm{d}^3q$, so that for $N$ particles is $(\int \mathrm{d}^3q)^N = V^N.$